# Question on exercise on graded rings and Laurent polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a graded ring and $0 \neq f \in R_1.$ Let $S = R[f^{-1}]_0.$ I am tasked with showing that $R[f^{-1}] = S[x, x^{-1}],$ the ring of Laurent polynomials. I am just confused on whether $S = R[f^{-1}]_0$ refers to the group of degree 0 homogeneous elements in the graded ring $R[f^{-1}].$

Also, if $R = \oplus_{i \in Z} R_i$ then I proved that $R[f^{-1}] = \oplus_{i \in Z} R_i[f^{-1}].$ So I don't know how $S[x, x^{-1}]$ can have enough "information" about $R$ to be isomorphic to $S[x, x^{-1}]$ because $S$ is only $R_0[f^{-1}].$ Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: I am fairly sure that $R\left[f^{-1}\right]_0$ refers to the $R$-module of degree-$0$ homogeneous elements in $R\left[f^{-1}\right]$.

Comment: Try arguing that the $S$-algebra homomorphism $S\left[x,x^{-1}\right] \to R\left[f^{-1}\right]$ that sends $x$ to the (invertible) element $f$ of $R\left[f^{-1}\right]$ is an isomorphism. The inverse map is the $R$-algebra homomorphism that sends each $r/f^m$, where $r \in R$ is homogeneous of degree $k$, to $\left(r/f^k\right) x^{k-m} \in S\left[x,x^{-1}\right]$ (note that $r/f^k \in S$).

Comment: Hmm I think I incorrectly assumed $R[f^{-1}]_0 = R_0[f^{-1}]$ when it should rather be $R_1[f^{-1}]$.

Comment: Careful: It is neither!

Comment: But 1 is in $R_1[f^{-1}]!$ Wouldn't that necessarily mean that $R[f^{-1}]_0 = R_1[f^{-1}]?$

Comment: No, it wouldn't. $R\left[f^{-1}\right]_0$ contains $rf^{-2}$ where $r$ is any homogeneous degree-$2$ element of $R$, for example. This is not in $R_1\left[f^{-1}\right]$. On the other hand, $R_1\left[f^{-1}\right]$ contains $R_1$, so it's in the wrong degree.

Comment: Brain fart!! But it seems as if the question regards $R[f^{-1}]_0$ as something unique. Is a graded ring decomposition $R = \oplus_{i \in Z}R_i$ always unique? I mean for example can't we have $R_0 = R$ and $R_i = 0$ for $i \neq 0$ be another graded ring decomposition?